# how to convert form values which is in a loop, into an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops

```
<?php 
    $question = array();
    $answer   = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
?>
<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Question No: <?php echo $i; ?></label>
            <?php echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='qu[$i]'><br/>";
            echo "<lable>Answer: </lable>";
            echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='ans[$i]'><br>";?>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<center><button name='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-home' style="width: 200px;">Submit</button></center>
```

Here is my code, I want to get all data which is entered in this form. But as a array. After submit the form, this form will collect the values from a loop, so I have to collect values from this loop and convert those to an array.

Comment: Why do you open `$num` forms? Keep the **form** tags outside the loop. And check what you get in `$_POST` when you submit the form.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, here $num means 5

Comment: nono the `$num` is fine, but dont open **5** forms, open one. And does your _form_ have an **action** or is it empty like here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea is fine up to the point where you open a new form **every time**.

Try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="" method="post">
  <?php 
    $question = array();
    $answer   = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
  ?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Question No: <?php echo $i; ?></label>
      <?php echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='qu[$i]'><br/>";
            echo "<lable>Answer: </lable>";
            echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='ans[$i]'><br>";?>        
    </div>
  <?php } ?>

    <center><button name='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-home' style="width: 200px;">Submit</button></center>

  </form>
</div>
```

And to check if this is what you want just `var_dump($_POST);` on the page that receives the request.

Comment: Actually I want to get the values of this from, as an array.

Comment: @AzharulIslam Ok, you should get them when you submit the form. What do you get when you submit the form?

Comment: Nothing, Because I didn't print anything right now. This is a form which is in a for-loop. And after submit the form, I want to get those values as a array which is entered on this form.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused. How are you testing this? When you submit the form the values shall be inside `$_POST` global on the page targeted by the _action_ attribute.

Comment: @AzharulIslam Glad I could help out :)